# Changing Windows display size uniformly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Why is it when I changed my Windows display size from 125% to 150%, my program's forms, which I made in with Visual C#, will be so big and nasty?

Is there a way to make these forms and their controls keep of their sizes without any changing whether I changed Windows display size or not?

Please don't tell me to use a tabular panel or any other container or layout, because I'm not complaining from forms or controls location.

Comment: time to consider wpf

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Form.AutoScaleMode` property.  I'm guessing it is set to `Font`.  Change it to `None` and it might behave like you are wanting.

Comment: Thank you friend , I did it but for sorry same result